# SEGFAULT : Makefile for Dynamic Library in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-library

I'm trying to create a Makefile that will compile and link a main file, selena-4.c, with my shared libary, lib-selena.so. The main file uses dlopen to use the shared library dynamically.

(For context: Our homework assignment was to take a previous homework, in which we had to create a program that created a linked list with the number of nodes the same as a command line entered by the user, and divide it up into different files(with header files) & practice creating shared libraries and static libraries. This is the last step: to create a new main file : selena-4.c & use dlopen to dynamically open the shared library that we created in a previous step.)

(I've already turned in my assignment, by the way, but I want to understand where I went wrong so that I do well on my final, which is tomorrow.)

When I run my makefile, I get this message:
lib-selena.so:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here is my main file:

```
#include "selena-4.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *tempHandle;

    tempHandle = dlopen("lib-selena.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!tempHandle) printf("%s\n", dlerror());

    int (*mainOne) (int argc, char **argv); 
    int (*mainTwo) (char **argv);
    int (*mainThree) (void);
    int (*mainFour) (void); 

    mainOne = dlsym(tempHandle, "main1");
    mainTwo = dlsym(tempHandle, "main2");
    mainThree = dlsym(tempHandle, "main3");
    mainFour = dlsym(tempHandle, "main4");

    mainOne(argc, &*argv);
    mainTwo(&*argv);
    mainThree();
    mainFour();

    dlclose(tempHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file for my main file:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//This global struct acts as a 'node' with pointers to preceding and following 
nodes, in addition to a unique number (the data field).
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;

};

typedef struct node _node; //our node struct will be referred to as '_node' 
from now on

extern _node *head;
extern _node *tail; 
extern _node *trashHead;
extern _node *trashTail;

int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
all: hw11FOUR

COMP = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC -c -Wall 


hw11FOUR: selena-4.o 
    gcc -o hw11FOUR selena-4.o -ldl

selena-4.o: selena-4.c  
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-4.c
```

Here is the Makefile that I used to create my shared library:

```
all: hw11THREE
COMP = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC -c -Wall 


hw11THREE: selena-main.o lib-selena.so
    gcc -o hw11THREE selena-main.o -lm ./lib-selena.so

selena-main.o: selena-main.c  selena-main.h
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-main.c 

selena-A.o: selena-A.c selena-A.h
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-A.c

selena-B.o: selena-B.c selena-B.h
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-B.c

selena-C.o: selena-C.c selena-C.h
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-C.c

selena-D.o: selena-D.c selena-D.h
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-D.c

lib-selena.so: selena-A.o selena-B.o selena-C.o selena-D.o 
    gcc -shared -o lib-selena.so selena-A.o selena-B.o selena-C.o selena-D.o
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you guys can offer me! Thank you!

EDIT: ORIGINAL MAKEFILE
    all: hw11FOUR

```
COMP = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC -c -Wall 


hw11FOUR: selena-4.o lib-selena.so
    gcc -o hw11FOUR selena-4.o -lm ./lib-selena.so -ldl

selena-4.o: selena-4.c  
    $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-4.c 

lib-selena.so: selena-4.o 
    gcc -shared -o lib-selena.so selena-4.o
```

Comment: How do you "run" your Makefile? Where is `lib-selena.so`, and what is your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (first, I suppose we should ask for which platform)?

Comment: Sorry if I used incorrect terminology. Answers to your questions: (1) make -f Makefile4 (2) It's created when I 'run the other makefile, by typing make -f Makefile3 (3) I'm unsure-- how can I find out? (4) what do you mean by platform? I'm doing this on linux - is that what you mean?

Comment: Where do you link your executable with `lib-selena.so`; you only link with the `dl` library. By the way, `lib-selena` is a bad name, since library name in the linker command becomes `-selena`, possibly with escaping the `-`. `libselena.so` is a better name.

Comment: Also, you may not want to declare `main` in a a header file. I've never seen it done, and perhaps it doesn't hurt, but it really is very uncommon.

Comment: oh, so I still need to do that even if I'm using dlopen? That's what I did for my original makefile but I changed it because I assumed I was doing something wrong. Here is my original makefile:

Comment: all: hw11FOUR

COMP = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC -c -Wall 


hw11FOUR: selena-4.o lib-selena.so
 gcc -o hw11FOUR selena-4.o -lm ./lib-selena.so -ldl

selena-4.o: selena-4.c  
 $(COMP) $(CFLAGS) selena-4.c 

lib-selena.so: selena-4.o 
 gcc -shared -o lib-selena.so selena-4.o

Comment: Well, I actually don't know why you use `dlopen`. Why can't you just link with the library instead?

Comment: this was a homework assignment. so the names of the files and the way we're supposed to do things were just directions from my professor. I added my original makefile to my main post also so it's easier to read

Comment: Well, going by the man-page for `dlopen`, if the filename argument to `dlopen` does not contain a slash, only the usual list of directories is search. As per Elliot's comment, make sure your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains the library. It's unclear to me whether `dlopen` needs `lib-selena.so` or just `-selena` as its name in this case. Alternatively, use the path option: `dlopen("./lib-selena.so", ...)` or whatever the path is.

Comment: @OP Note: you have no error-checks in your code after `dlopen` and `dlsym` -- that's unacceptable in a school-projects (or in a real-life project)